# Gradle Faild:ASCII

Tags: android, firebase

i'm using android 3.0.1. i began use firebase with android. after adding json file and updating  both gradle file , i have got error message at the top of screen: **Gradle project sync failed:Basic  functionality (eg. editing , debugging) will not work**. and down in the thin bar below : **Gradle failed: ASCII** as seen at below pic

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1hx2.png)

when i clicked ***Open File*** link occur below  at pic,it opens ***build.gradle(Module: app)***. 
To solve this issue, i have tried :
1- use gradle 4.4.1 instead of current one (file->settings->Gradle->use local gradle distribution).
2 -downgrade com.google.gms:google-services 4.3.0 or 4.2.0 - current is 4.3.3

but all useless.

any idea?

build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
       // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build .gradle(Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abdalla.home.ecommerce"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
  //  compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed dependency at gradle.build - Project as follows :

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
```

took a long time to sync successfully but succeeded at the end. i could not understand the logic behind.